# Problen with PyQt5, Python3 and Anaconda3 on MacOSX Mavericks

Tags: python-3.x, macos, pyqt5

I would especially like to have a feedback with people who develop in Python on Mac OSX.

I develop an application that behaves very well under GNU / Linux and Windows (I already created executables of the app under both systems with PyInstaller).

I have virtualized (with VirtualBox) an OSX Mavericks (updated to version 10.9.5) because I would also like to distribute my software under this system.

I installed Miniconda (with Python 3.7.1 and ... with among others the module PyQt5 -> pyqt-5.9.2). I set up a virtual environment for my application and I access without worry (by the way, Anaconda is really good).

Still, I have a problem importing QtGui and QtCore (there seems to be a big problem with QtCore on Mac OSX):

```
    (apsc) Mac-Pro-de-angelo:apsc angelo$ python apsc_gui.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "apsc_gui.py", line 11, in <module>
    from moteur_apsc.exec_pdfkit_seq_prof_gui import APSC_Sequence_Prof
  File "/Users/angelo/miniconda3/envs/apsc/moteur_apsc/exec_pdfkit_seq_prof_gui.py", line 27, in <module>
    from affichage_apsc.push_button_icone_droite import PushButtonIconeDroite
  File "/Users/angelo/miniconda3/envs/apsc/affichage_apsc/push_button_icone_droite.py", line 10, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/angelo/miniconda3/envs/apsc/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyQt5/QtCore.so, 2): Symbol not found: _LSCopyDefaultApplicationURLForURL
  Referenced from: /Users/angelo/miniconda3/envs/apsc/lib/libQt5Core.5.dylib
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices
 in /Users/angelo/miniconda3/envs/apsc/lib/libQt5Core.5.dylib
(apsc) Mac-Pro-de-angelo:apsc angelo$
```

If I just import QtGui through the terminal, the problem is the same:

```
Mac-Pro-de-angelo:bin angelo$ conda activate apsc
(apsc) Mac-Pro-de-angelo:bin angelo$ python
Python 3.7.1 (default, Dec 14 2018, 13:28:58) 
[Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] :: Anaconda custom (64-bit) on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from PyQt5 import QtGui
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/angelo/miniconda3/envs/apsc/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyQt5/QtGui.so, 2): Symbol not found: _LSCopyDefaultApplicationURLForURL
  Referenced from: /Users/angelo/miniconda3/envs/apsc/lib/libQt5Core.5.dylib
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices
 in /Users/angelo/miniconda3/envs/apsc/lib/libQt5Core.5.dylib
>>>
```

Can you help me get around the problem and / or know exactly what is going on?

Thanks in advance for all the help you can give me.

Good evening.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have started with checking whether your `LaunchServices` has this symbol

```
nm /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/LaunchServices | grep _LSCopyDefaultApplicationURLForURL
```

is it possible that you have QtGui compiled with more recent version of OSX?

Comment: You mean it would be better to use Anaconda3 a newer version of OSX?

In fact I virtualized OSX with VirtualBox in Kubuntu 14.04 (after some small tests there is only the Mavericks version that I could not install).
I installed Anaconda3 with this package: Miniconda3-latest-MacOSX-x86_64.pkg

Comment: Well, it looks like the issue you have is related to libQt5Core.5.dylib. It looks like Qt5 is not supported at your system (10.9): https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/macos.html

Comment: What should I do then?

Comment: You can always try with older release of Qt: http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/supported-platforms.html

Comment: Meanwhile, as I am a stubborn guy, I tried to find a solution anyway. In fact Anaconda3 (which is really great! Is my point of view) allows to install virtualized environments with different versions of Python (depending on the projects). So I reinstalled my work environment with a version 3.4 of Python ... and luckily Python 3.4 (3.4.5) installs on Anaconda3 with pyqt-5.6.0, qt-5.6.2 and sip-4.18. I could start without any problem my software. Even Spyder (Spyder3, installed by default in Anaconda3) works (it is very slow to start, but I'm happy with it anyway). I am really happy !